# PHP SQL - OR condition within SELECT based on if exists

Tags: php, mysql

I have a select statement which I would like some help on. I would like to select a record based on an `OR` statement if the first option is not met. For example:

```
SELECT `col1` FROM myTable WHERE `col3` LIKE 'foo%' OR `col3` LIKE 'boo%'
```

In the above example i only want `boo%` searched if `foo%` is not found.

This is part of a much larger query so optimisation would be important.

Comment: Do you mean : if the `%foo%` request returns something, keep it that way, otherwise if it returns 0 elements, search for `%boo%`?

Comment: Hold on for a second, what is wrong with your query? A column can start with `foo` or `boo` but not both.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separe rows where both of the operands are true,you can use XOR instead of OR